# Python multiply range

Tags: python, arrays, range

i need to get a list of numbers derived from a range(15,20,1), were each number is 15*x*100:

```
X   Y
15  100
16  93,75
17  88,2352941176
18  83,3333333333
19  78,9473684211
20  75
```

The result should be an array of y with two decimals.

I tried with python and it took me a while to find out that it will only handle integers. Then I tried numpy, but I am still not getting there.  I am a nub, so sorry for the stupidity of the question, but after trying for two hours I decided to post a question.

Best,
Mace

Comment: Downvoting his first ever question will surely encourage him.

Comment: I'm confused by what you're looking for as the output. I don't see how the example relates to your first statement.

Comment: I think, you wanted to say `1500 / x`, not `x * 1500`

Comment: I'm also confused about this.  Python handles floating point numbers just fine.  I take it that the in your locale, the `,` represents a decimal separator so you have 2 columns of numbers here, but I don't see how `Y` relates to `15*x*100`.  Could you show us the code you're working with?  That might help us figure out what you're going for here ...

Comment: It looks like I am not the only one confused. @mace: Could you please try to explain what does "range(15,20,1)" X and Y mean in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for something like:

```
>>> print [float(15)/x*100 for x in range(15,21)]
[100.0, 93.75, 88.23529411764706, 83.33333333333334, 78.94736842105263, 75.0]
```

This doesn't give you the number to 2 decimal places.  For that you'll need `round` or string formatting ... (I'm not sure exactly what you want to do with the numbers after the fact, so it's hard to give a recommendation here).  Here's an example with string formatting:

```
>>> print ['{0:.2f}'.format(float(15)/x*100) for x in range(15,21)]
['100.00', '93.75', '88.24', '83.33', '78.95', '75.00']
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you need something like:

```
ylist = [float(x)*15*100 for x in range(15,21)]
```

?

This would return:

```
[22500.0, 24000.0, 25500.0, 27000.0, 28500.0, 30000.0]
```

I'm not quite sure what your Y column means, since your formula `15*x*100` doesn't generate those values.

If you actually mean `x*100/15`, it would be:

```
ylist = [15/float(x)*100 for x in range(15,21)]
```

Or even simpler:

```
ylist = [15.0/x*100.0 for x in range(15,21)]
```

If all the values in a calculation are of type `int`, python will create an `int` as result. If, on the other hand, one of them is a `float` or `double`, that'll be the type of the result.

This coercion can be done both explicitly using `float(x)`, or simply having one of your constants represented as a floating point value, like `100.0`.

As to the 2 decimal places need, it depends on what you need to do with the values.

One way is to use `round` to 2 decimal places, like:

```
ylist = [round(15.0/x*100.0, 2) for x in range(15,21)]
```

If you always need two decimal places, probably you'll want to use string formatting, check @mgilson reply for that.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.
It was indeed (15 / x) * 100. Mixed that up.

ylist = [15/float(x)*100 for x in range(15,31,1)]
Solved the problem.
thanks a lot!